# Send a buy transaction to magic eden market on Solana Blockchain with python

Tags: python, solana, solana-transaction-instruction

i want to buy an nft which is already listed on Magic Eden,
is there a way to make it possible ?

i think the transaction would be like this :

instruction = buy(nft_address,receiver_adr,magic_eden_program_id, price)
send_tx = client.send_transaction(transaction, sender_keypair)

nft_address : is the address of the nft that i want to buy
receiver_adr : my public address
magic_eden_program_id : M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K
price : the price of the nft on magic eden market place

i have look at [Sending solana transactions with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69174931/sending-solana-transactions-with-python)
but i don't see how i can use it with magic eden.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use ME API. But, the default language there is not python. I'm also still learning. We can discuss more together. Add my discord: Yohan#9481

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Excuse my question but where can i find the magiceden api that make you send "buy instructions". The only one that i know is https://api.magiceden.dev/ but it does not send list instructions or buy instructions

Comment: @yohan i sent you an invitation from perfect#2691 in discord if you are still interested

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?