# solana-python call contract method

Tags: python, solana, contract

Currently, I trying to access the contract of solana with python based env.
I want to try simple test like that.

1. Access the contract of solana
2. Access the function(hello) with solana-py

The solana contract info is here (devnet): https://explorer.solana.com/address/78PoQT2bBAJiQxk3qBshvxvFEiPeARDAzYE6zwqpbnUv?cluster=devnet

I searched some related information in StackOverflow are below:

- [Solana spl token transfer python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70923875/solana-spl-token-transfer-python)
- [Sending solana transactions with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69174931/sending-solana-transactions-with-python)

How to access the contract function in solana using python?
In the solidity env, I just create an instance with abi and contract address.
However, I thought that solana contract is a little complex.

Comment: It would be useful to add information or source code for your program, and any existing JS or Rust client that may already exist for it.

Comment: I just use python for accessing the contract of Solana.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? I am looking for a similar solution

Comment: Sorry for late response. Check the below answer that is helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find a simple example for transferring tokens. I guess that is helping some who want to handle tokens in Solana.

```
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from solana.system_program import TransferParams, transfer
from solana.transaction import Transaction
from solana.rpc.api import Client

import base58

http_client = Client("https://api.devnet.solana.com")
sender_pri = ''
receiver_pub = ''

def load_wallet():
    byte_array = base58.b58decode(sender_pri)
    account = Keypair.from_secret_key(byte_array)
    return account

def send_sol(receiver, amount):
    try:
        sender = load_wallet()

        txn = Transaction().add(transfer(TransferParams(
            from_pubkey=sender.public_key, to_pubkey=PublicKey(receiver), lamports=amount)))
        resp = http_client.send_transaction(txn, sender)

        transaction_id = resp['result']
        if transaction_id != None:
            return transaction_id
        else:
            return None

    except Exception as e:
        print('error:', e)
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_sol(receiver_pub, 1)
```

Comment: Which library did you install ?